# Why does Kotlin Activity have a problem finding Buttons?

Tags: android, kotlin

Attempting to update an older Android game project to use view binding. Android Studio version 4.1.3. I am thinking my problem has to do with the naming of my binding class.
the xml file is called activity_correct_guess.xml and I am using what I think is the name that gets generated by the view binding: ActivityCorrectGuessBinding. Appreciate and ideas!

The build errors:

Unresolved reference: ActivityCorrectGuessBinding
Unresolved reference: binding
Unresolved reference: binding

In the Gradle build module I have the following:

```
    android {
       compileSdkVersion 30
       buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"  
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

layout file: activity_correct_guess.xml

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPlayAgain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ..... />
```

Activity file: CorrectGuessActivity.kt

```
      class CorrectGuessActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      val binding = ActivityCorrectGuessBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
      val view = binding.root
      setContentView(view)

      playAgain()
      exitGame()
   }

fun playAgain() {
    binding.btnPlayAgain.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent("com.appkotlin2021v4.MainActivity")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: your binding is a local variable within `onCreate`, of course you can't access it from another method.

Comment: Yes, this is correct thanks very much. I fixed the scope problem and am now getting  the error: Unresolved reference: ActivityCorrectGuessBinding. The generated class in the databinding directory is 'ActivityCorrectGuessImpl' . The doc says 'A binding class is generated for each layout file. By default, the name of the class is based on the name of the layout file, converting it to Pascal case and adding the Binding suffix to it' so I am still wondering what is going on with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you define your view binding in the root of your Activity or Fragment or in an `init` block:

```kotlin
class CorrectGuessActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //get to inflating!
    private val binding = ActivityCorrectGuessBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        playAgain()
        exitGame()
    }

    fun playAgain() {
        binding.btnPlayAgain.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent("com.appkotlin2021v4.MainActivity")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
}
```

The only time you need to "wait to inflate" is when you're in a non-ViewGroup-based class like `RecyclerView.Adapter`, etc.

Comment: You can’t inflate a binding from a property initializer. The `layoutInflater` will be null. The property needs to be `lazy` or `lateinit`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct way to define the view binding. thank you!